# How to execute annotate in Django model with foreign keys?

Tags: django, django-models

Django novice question here :)

I have the following model

```
Domain:
   domain_name
   domain_description
```

These domains can be scanned multiple times

The other model is

```
ScanHistory:
   last_scan_date
   scan_status
   domain_name = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When scanned, these domains produce several subdomains

```
ScannedHost:
    subdomain
    cname
    scan_history = models.ForeignKey(ScanHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

These subdomains will have vulnerabilities associated with it

```
VulnerabilityScan:
    vulnerability_of = models.ForeignKey(ScanHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    severity
    vulnerability_name
```

How do I find out the domain which are top 3 most vulnerable Domain? A most vulnerable Domain is any domain that has the highest count of Unique Vulnerability despite n numbers of time it is scanned.

I stumbled upon Django annotate, but I don't seem to solve this.

Comment: So that is the *unique* `vulnerability_name`? Shouldn't it make more sense to have a `Vunerability` model that has a name (and perhaps additional information like `severity`)?

Comment: The vulnerabilityScan model itself has vulnerability_name already. Do we need another Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can annotate with the `Count` of distinct `vulnerability_name`s:

```
Domain.objects.annotate(
    num_vul=Count(
        'scanhistory__scannedhost__vulnerabilityscan__vulnerability_name',
        distinct=True
    )
).order_by('-num_vul')[:3]
```

The [**`distinct=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct) part will ensure that we count each `vulnerability_name` only once.

We here query the `ForeignKey`s in reverse, we do this by using the [**`related_query_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) which specifys how to query in reverse. In case that is not specified, Django will use the [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), and if both are not specified use the name of the class in lowercase, so `scanhistory`, `scannedhost`, and `vulnerabilityscan`.

That being said, it might be better to model this with a `Vulnerability` model, that can contain the name of the vulnerability, the severity, etc. so:

```
class Vulnerability(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    severity = models.IntegerField()

class VulnerabilityScan(models.Model):
    vulnerability_of = models.ForeignKey(ScanHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vulnerability = models.ForeignKey(
        Vulnerability,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Then we can count with:

```
Domain.objects.annotate(
    num_vul=Count(
        'scanhistory__scannedhost__vulnerabilityscan__vulnerability',
        distinct=True
    )
).order_by('-num_vul')[:3]
```

Comment: Willem, any idea on how do I count the number of vulnerabilities from Django Template?

This will return the Domain objects with highest vuln count, I want to display most vuln domain with the counts as well.

I saw something similar to this 
{% for item in most_vuln_target %}
{{item.scanhistory_set.all|length}}
{% endfor %}
This generated number of times it is scanned, but how do I extend this to the total number of vulns?
Thank you

Comment: @YogeshOjha: the domains that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.num_vulnerability`, so if you use the queryset of this answer in the template, you can work with `{% for domain in domains %}{{ domain.domain_name }}: {{ domain.num_vul }}{% endfor %}`.